# Why does a Heroku-hosted application take so long to start up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently created my first Heroku application and I'm finding some strange behavior:

When the application hasn't been accessed in a while, I think the server shuts down.  Then, if you access it, it takes about 20 seconds to start up before it responds.  After this initial start up phase, it responds quickly.

Is there a way to avoid this "start up / shut down" phase?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, pay for a full-time dyno. The Heroku docs state that when you're on the free tier if your dyno is not in use for a while (30 minutes in my experience) it shuts down. It restarts the next time it receives a request.

See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#frequently-asked-questions

Heroku refers to his as "Dyno Idling."

Comment: What type of dyno I shall pay for a full time ? is it Web Dyno ? Or Worker Dyno ?

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively to Andrew's answer, and/or if you cannot afford an additional dyno, you can implement the New Relic RPM add-on and use their "availability monitoring" feature.

It will basically ping your application twice per minute, thus preventing the dyno from idling. Plus you get the performance measurement features.

Comment: I like the way you think, Pierre!  I went with Pingdom, but its the same concept. :)

Answer (score 9):

It's because of dynos stating. You can just ping your app to keep it started. Checkout this post:

http://codeglot.com/posts/25-simple_way_to_keep_smaller_apps_loaded_on_herkou